# ACF accessing a field from the query, but not in post

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I'm not sure if this is possible - but checking before re-writing the template.

I've extended wp_query to allow for a geocode/location search to be performed.
This is working in itself and returning posts in a nearest to search point first order.

In the query generated now by wp_query it's calculating the distance in miles away from the search point and returning this `AS distance`.

My colleague who's built the results template has used ACF - so is looping through the list using:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

This 'distance' value is not being returned when using the usual ACF method of `<?php echo the_field('distance'); ?>` which makes sense as it's not an ACF or post field, but rather calculated in the wp_query...

Is there a good way of accessing values from the query, but not ACF fields, inside this ACF loop - or am I better rewriting to manually look through the query results without the ACF methods?

Comment: Isn't that just the regular WP loop? Don't think this is related to ACF, since as you say this distance-thing isn't a custom field and ACF is made for working with those. Not sure how you build this without seeing more code. But couldn't you go something like ``$post->distance`` ?

Comment: I'm being so dense today - you're right, it's just in $post. If you want to post that as an answer will accept thanks for that.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Answer posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that just the regular WP loop? Don't think this is related to ACF, since as you say this distance-thing isn't a custom field and ACF is made for working with those.

Not sure how you build this without seeing more code. But couldn't you go something like `$post->distance` ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should work the way it is described in your question of default code for Advance custom fields
Also as custom field are part of post you can use `$post->name of custom field` also.